# Canvas text in the middle of Image

Tags: javascript

how to make text in the middle of basket? 
I've tried that but text isn't in the middle. [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU9Xp.jpg)

```
function draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(basket1, 200, canvas.height - (basket1.height + 50));
    ctx.drawImage(basket2, canvas.width - basket2.width - 200, canvas.height - (basket1.height + 50))
    ctx.drawImage(basket3, canvas.width / 2 - basket3.width / 2, canvas.height - (basket1.height + 50));

    ctx.font = '24px serif';
    ctx.fillText(score_basket_1, basket1.width / 2 + 200, canvas.height - (basket2.height));

    update();
}

function update() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.textAlign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textAlign), in particular:

```
ctx.textAlign = 'center'
```

You might also be interested in [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.textBaseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline), which performs a similar task for the vertical axis:

```
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle'
```